# Redirect subprocess.run output to jupyter notebook's

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using the new (from 3.5 forward) `subprocess.run` command from inside a jupyter notebook.

Normally, running this code in a python console I'll get the output of a `.run()` call printed to the console, but that is not true for Jupyter notebooks.

How can I redirect the `.run()` output to Jupyter's?

**NOTICE** Consider a command which is a running output, printing a line very few seconds, so approaches that capture the entire output and then prints it is out of the question, I want the printing to be done in a live manner

Answer (score 0):

EDITED ANSWER:

user Popen instead of run() and then:

```
x = subprocess.Popen(...,stdout=subprocess.STDOUT)
while True:
    line = x.stdout.readline()
    do whatever you want and decide if to print this line or not
```

Comment: This exactly what I don't want, just like my NOTICE says, this captures the ENTIRE output, and then prints it when it is done, I want to be able to print in a "live" manner

Comment: I'll try it, is there something I could change `while True` with so it would stop when the command has finished or an error has occured?

Comment: i;m sure there is a way - maybe try communicate() in the loop and when you get returncode? , need to check it

Comment: This while true will never end, so this answer is not really useful :/

Comment: it will end when you read specific line and do break from it. or as i said you will need to communicate